# Confused by type registration and implementation of DI, IoC, Unity and Moq

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I've got some free time at the moment so am trying to get my head around DI and IoC containers. I've picked unity for no reason other than from what I can tell there are no major differences between the major frameworks that I should be too concerned about starting out. As things get more complex later I realise I may need to change but for now I'm hoping it will do.

So, I'm working with a relatively simple data access scenario and have implemented the following interface, and data access class.

```
public interface IEventRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Event> GetAll();
}

public class EventRepository : IEventRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Event> GetAll()
    {
        // Data access code here
    }
}
```

Then to use I can do the following.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType(typeof(IEventRepository), typeof(EventRepository));

var eventRepo = container.Resolve<IEventRepository>();
eventRepo.GetAll();
```

If I needed to change my database provider in 6 months from what I understand I create a new implementation of IEventRepository and update the the type registration, that's fine.

**Now, here is where I'm confused.** If for example I wanted to implement some caching I could inherit from the appropriate implementation of IEventRepository and override the appropriate methods to implement the necessary caching. However, doing so this way would make it harder to test caching is working correctly using a Moq implementation passed in via DI so in the true spirit of DI I thought it would make sense to create an implementation of IEventRepository, then use DI to request an actual data access implementation of IEventRepository like so.

```
public class CachedEventRepository : IEventRepository
{
    private readonly IEventRepository _eventRepo;

    public CachedEventRepository(IEventRepository eventRepo)
    {
        if (eventRepo is CachedEventRepository)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot pass a CachedEventRepository to a CachedEventRepository");

        _eventRepo = eventRepo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Event> GetAll()
    {
        // Appropriate caching code ultimately calling _eventRepo.GetAll() if needed
    }
}
```

Does this make sense or am I going about this all wrong? What would you suggest? If I am doing it correctly how do I resolve the following situation so that the CachedEventRepository gets the appropriate data access implementation of IEventRepository?

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType(typeof(IEventRepository), typeof(EventRepository));
container.RegisterType(typeof(IEventRepository), typeof(CachedEventRepository));

var eventRepo = container.Resolve<IEventRepository>();
eventRepo.GetAll();
```

Many thanks for your help.

**Edit 1**
The following is a Moq test I was hoping I would be able to perform, which I don't think would be possible using inheritance and would require DI.

```
var cacheProvider = new MemoryCaching();

var eventRepo = new Mock<IEventRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
eventRepo
    .Setup(x => x.GetAll())
    .Returns(() =>
    {
        return new Event[] { 
            new Event() { Id = 1}, 
            new Event() { Id = 2}
        };
    });

var cachedEventRepo = new CachedEventRepository(
    eventRepo.Object, 
    cacheProvider);

var data = cachedEventRepo.GetAll();
data = cachedEventRepo.GetAll();
data = cachedEventRepo.GetAll();
Assert.IsTrue(data.Count() > 0);
eventRepo.Verify(x => x.GetAll(), Times.Once());

// This set method should expire the cache so next time get all is requested it should
// load from the database again
cachedEventRepo.SomeSetMethod();

data = cachedEventRepo.GetAll();
data = cachedEventRepo.GetAll();
Assert.IsTrue(data.Count() > 0);
eventRepo.Verify(x => x.GetAll(), Times.Exactly(2));
```

Comment: You should not test a cache logc in the eventRepo unit-test. It brokes a Single responsibility idea of SOLID paradigm.

Comment: I'm testing caching and eventRepo separately. What I'm trying to test is the integration of the two together, for example making sure a set method expires the appropriate caches.

Comment: Yes, yes, I got it. I have no more ideas now.

Comment: What do you think about my variant in my **update**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some thinking on the subject and some research on Unity I came up with this.

```
public class EventRepository : IEventRepository
{
    private readonly IDbManager _dbManager;

    public EventRepository(IDbManager dbManager)
    {
        _dbManager = dbManager;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Event> GetAll()
    {
        // Data access code
    }
}

public class CachedEventRepository : IEventRepository
{
    private readonly ICacheProvider _cacheProvider;
    private readonly IEventRepository _eventRepo;

    public ICacheProvider CacheProvider
    {
        get { return _cacheProvider; }
    }

    public CachedEventRepository(IEventRepository eventRepo, ICacheProvider cacheProvider)
    {
        if(eventRepo is CachedEventRepository)
            throw new ArgumentException("eventRepo cannot be of type CachedEventRepository", "eventRepo");

        _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
        _eventRepo = eventRepo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Event> GetAll()
    {
        // Caching logic for this method with a call to _eventRepo.GetAll() if required
    }
}
```

This requires the following unity registration. A resolution request for IEventRepository will return a CachedEventRepository. If I want to remove caching quickly I simply remove that CachedEventRepository registration and it will revert back to EventRepository.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IDbManager, SqlDbManager>();
container.RegisterType<ICacheProvider, MemoryCaching>();
container.RegisterType<IEventRepository, EventRepository>();
container.RegisterType<IEventRepository, CachedEventRepository>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<EventRepository>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<ICacheProvider>())
    );
```

This then allows exactly the tests I'm after.

A simple data access test... Does the SQL work

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IDbManager, SqlDbManager>();
container.RegisterType<EventRepository>();

var repo = container.Resolve<EventRepository>();

var data = repo.GetAll();

Assert.IsTrue(data.Count() > 0);
```

A simple cache test... Does the caching system work

```
var cache = new MemoryCaching();

var getVal = cache.Get<Int32>(
    "TestKey",
    () => { return 2; },
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5));

Assert.AreEqual(2, getVal);

getVal = cache.Get<Int32>(
    "TestKey",
    () => { throw new Exception("This should not be called as the value should be cached"); },
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5));

Assert.AreEqual(2, getVal);
```

And a test of the two working together... Does the caching **on the individual methods** work as expected. Does the cache expire when it should, do method argument work correctly to trigger new database requests, etc.

```
var cacheProvider = new MemoryCaching();

var eventRepo = new Mock<IEventRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
eventRepo
    .Setup(x => x.GetAll())
    .Returns(() =>
    {
        return new Event[] { 
            new Event() { Id = 1}, 
            new Event() { Id = 2}
        };
    });

var cachedEventRepo = new CachedEventRepository(
    eventRepo.Object,
    cacheProvider);


cachedEventRepo.CacheProvider.Clear();
var data = cachedEventRepo.GetAll();
data = cachedEventRepo.GetAll();
data = cachedEventRepo.GetAll();
Assert.IsTrue(data.Count() > 0);
eventRepo.Verify(x => x.GetAll(), Times.Once());


cachedEventRepo.SomeSetMethodWhichExpiresTheCache();
data = cachedEventRepo.GetAll();
data = cachedEventRepo.GetAll();
Assert.IsTrue(data.Count() > 0);
eventRepo.Verify(x => x.GetAll(), Times.Exactly(2));
```

What do you think of this? I think it offers good separation and good testability.

Comment: Yes, this one is much better then your first variant.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to encapsulate all cache logic in one class? 
So you'll get something like that:

```
public interface ICacheManager {}
```

and

```
public class CacheManager : ICacheManager {}
```

So, you could write all you unit-test to ensure that your cache logic is OK. And it will be `CacheManagerTest` class!

Then you can change you class in this way:

```
public class EventRepository : IEventRepository
{
private ICacheManager _cacheManager;
public EventRepository(ICacheManager cacheManager)
{
    _cacheManager = cacheManager;
}
    public IEnumerable<Event> GetAll()
    {
        // Data access code here
    }
}
```

So, you don't need to test cache logic in your `EventRepositoryTest` class, cose it's alredy tested.

than you can set up you IoC container to return an instance of ICacheManager with some paramater of Cache policy.

**Update**
Ok, last try:

```
public interface IEventRepo
{
    IEnumerable<Event> GetAll();
}

public interface ICacheProvider
{
    bool IsDataCached();
    IEnumerable<Event> GetFromCache();
}

public class CacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{

    public bool IsDataCached()
    {
        //do smth
    }

    public IEnumerable<Event> GetFromCache()
    {
        //get smth
    }
}


public class EventRepo : IEventRepo
{
    private ICacheProvider _cacheProvider;

    public EventRepo(ICacheProvider cacheProvider)
    {
     _cacheProvider = cacheProvider
    }

    public IEnumerable<Event> GetAll()
    {
        if (_cacheProvider.IsDataCached())
        {
            return _cacheProvider.GetFromCache();
        }
        else
        {
            //get from repo, save data in cache etc
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class EventRepoTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetsDataFromCacheIfDataIsCachedTest()
    {
        var cacheProvider = new Mock<ICacheProvider>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        cacheProvider
            .Setup(x => x.IsDataCached())
            .Returns(() =>
            {
                return true;
            });
        cacheProvider
            .Setup(x => x.GetFromCache())
            .Returns(
            () => {
            return new Event[] { 
                new Event() { Id = 1}, 
                new Event() { Id = 2}
                };
            }
            );
        var eventRepo = new EventRepo(cacheProvider.Object);

        var data = eventRepo.GetAll();
        cacheProvider.Verify(x => x.GetFromCache(), Times.Once());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetsDataFromDataBaseIfNotCachedTest()
    {
        var cacheProvider = new Mock<ICacheProvider>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        cacheProvider
            .Setup(x => x.IsDataCached())
            .Returns(() =>
            {
                return false;
            });
        cacheProvider
            .Setup(x => x.GetFromCache())
            .Returns(
            () =>
            {
                return new Event[] { 
                new Event() { Id = 1}, 
                new Event() { Id = 2}
                };
            }
            );
        var eventRepo = new EventRepo(cacheProvider.Object);

        var data = eventRepo.GetAll();
        cacheProvider.Verify(x => x.GetFromCache(), Times.Never());
    }
}
```

Not sure in Moq syntax because there is no Moq for WinPhone, but I think it's not a problem.

Comment: I'm part way to your suggested implementation in that I have created an ICacheProvider and memory cache implementation. However, I was reluctant to inject it into EventRepository because that would prevent testing EventRepository detached from the caching logic.

Comment: In unit-test you can inject a simple cache provider, wich just return mock data or even do nothing. So you can avoid double testing of cache logic.

Comment: It would be double testing Cache logic to a degree. I'm not testing Caching directly and I'm not testing the data eventRepository, i'm testing the implementation of the two joined together to create cachedEventRepository. So, checking appropriate methods automatically expire the cache, cause a cache update, etc.

Comment: Ok, I see. But I don't think it is so nessesary to have a test in your **Edit**. If you have well tested 'CacheProvider' and well tested 'EventRepo' it's enough to test only unique logic of 'CachedEventRepository' if there is any. Anyway I'll check this page to see new ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I came up with another idea this morning and have posted it as a possible answer. I think it covers everything I'm after and still offers proper separation. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with a CachedEventRepository, but I would make the EventRepository's GetAll method virtual, and have CachedEventRepository subclass EventRepoistory.  Then the subclass can override GetAll, check cache, and if it finds nothing call base.GetAll.  It can then cache the results and return the list.

In this way the caching logic is separate from the data access logic, and the subclass is adding caching behavior to your repository.

You can then choose if you want a cached repository, say from a configuration file and configure the Unity container appropriately.

Also, you can have an interface for your caching service as well, so that you can mock that away when unit testing your CachedEventRepository.

Comment: My only concern with doing it this way is I cannot pass in a dependent EventRepository so I can Moq one and make sure the mocked method is called x number of times over a specific period after cache clearing and what not

Comment: @Hawxby I'm not sure I follow.  The Cached subclass takes an `ICachingService` interface.  Its up to your implementation of that interface to actually cache for the correct period of time.  The Cached repository should be completely ignorant of how the caching is actually done; it should always attempt to get from cache, and if it gets nothing should hit the database.  Otherwise your Cached repository is doing two things; managing the cache as well as utilizing the cache, a violation of Separation of Concerns.

Comment: take a look at my edit on the question, I think that demonstrates what I'm after in testing.